# Why does the Laplace transform of $t^2 \exp(at)$ exist?

Tags: exponential-function, laplace-transform

My book states a theorem :

"Let $f(t)$ be a function piecewise continuous on $[0, A]$ for $ A > 0$ and have an exponential order at infinity with $|f(t)| \leq M \exp(at)$. Then the Laplace transform is defined for $s > a$."

But the Laplace transforms of $t \exp(at)$ and $t^n \exp(at)$ are defined and found in most tables of Laplace transforms. How can this be when they both grow faster than $M\exp(at)$ for $t > 0$, which means they are not of exponential order.

One of the conditions for existence of the transform is that $f(t)$ be of exponential order, but this is clearly not the case.

What am I overlooking here? Both my intuition and the theorem seem to be saying that these Laplace transforms should not be defined.

Comment: Both $t\mapsto t\exp(at)$ and $t\mapsto t^n\exp(at)$ ARE of exponential order, for example they are controlled by $t\mapsto \exp((a+1)t)$ at infinity.

Comment: yes @Did 's comment provides the answer

Comment: I see what you are saying. But would it not be the case that $|\exp((a+1)t)|$ is STILL not $\leq M exp((at))$? That is, it seems to me that $\exp((a+1)t)$ still grows faster than $\exp(at)$, so I don't quite see why it is of exponential order.

Comment: well, what is $a$? Why do you insist on _the same_ $a$? What is wrong with exp order $M\exp((a+1)t)$? Would it help if you call $a+1$ $a'$ or $b$ or something else, and talk about exp order $M\exp((bt)$?

Comment: Ah, I think it is clear to me now. The function is of exponential order because it is of the same form as $\exp(at)$. I was interpreting the definition of exponential order too literally, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Let's show that in general, for $a \in \mathbf{C}$ and a polynomial $p$, that $p(t) \mathrm{e}^{at}$ is of exponential type $\Re(a) + \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Recall that a function $f\colon [0, \infty) \to \mathbf{C}$ is of exponential type $A$ if there exists a constant $C$ such that

$$|f(t)| \le C\mathrm{e}^{At}$$

for all $t \ge 0$. Suppose $\varepsilon > 0$. By l'Hopital's rule,

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}p(t)/\mathrm{e}^{\varepsilon t} = 0.$$

This means there exists a number $T$ such that $|p(t)/\mathrm{e}^{\varepsilon t}| < 1$ if $t > T$. Now, the function $t\mapsto p(t)/\mathrm{e}^{\varepsilon t}$ is continuous on the compact interval $[0, T]$, and is hence bounded there. That is, there exists $B$ such that $|p(t)/\mathrm{e}^{\varepsilon t}| \le B$ for all $t \in [0, R]$. Thus, we may say that $|p(t)/\mathrm{e}^{\varepsilon t}| \le B + 1$ for *all* $t \ge 0$, and so

$$|p(t)| \le (B + 1)\mathrm{e}^{\varepsilon t} \quad \text{ for all $t\ge0$}.$$

Hence, $|p(t)\mathrm{e}^{at}| \le (B + 1)\mathrm{e}^{\varepsilon t}|\mathrm{e}^{at}| = (\underbrace{B + 1}_{C})\mathrm{e}^{(\overbrace{\Re(a) + \varepsilon}^{A})t}$ for all $t \ge 0$, as required.